# Validity of Schengen Visa after first visit

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, italy, switzerland, sweden

I have a valid Schengen visa which was used for a business trip to Sweden in Oct 2019. It's valid upto 1 year and is a type 'C' visa with multiple entries allowed.

Now, I want to visit Italy(maximum stay) and Switzerland in February 2020 for tourism purpose. Do I need to get fresh visa for this visit or will the old visa suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a business visa include a visit/tourist visit.

The days in October 2019 may count for the 90/180 days rule, depening on the exact exit date planned.

- exit date in 2020 minus 180 days ; how many days in Schengen Area must be less than 90 days